# A noun meaning a consumer who bargains

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

Imagine you have a seller and a buyer who engage in bargaining at a market. Is there a **one-word noun** that describes a consumer who haggles (but not the seller)? I thought haggler, but that can be applied to both sides.

I want to distinguish between the members of a pair who engage in bargaining. I can call one the seller, but I can't really call the other a buyer, because the purchase does not happen if the bargaining fails (I guess the same objection can be made to the use of seller). I think offerer comes closest to what I am looking for, though I suppose a seller can also be an offerer.

Comment: Related question that will have a lot of applicable answers: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/164859/45432

Comment: *Bargain hunter* was the first one that came to mind.

Comment: `...describes a consumer who haggles (but not the seller)` I don't quite see how a consumer can bargain without the cooperation of the seller. It would be a one-step process: the buyer asking and the seller refusing.

Comment: @JimMack You are right: it does take two to tango. I will try to clarify in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Matt is spot-on with bargain hunter.

Secondly, I know you'd probably reject it because you're looking for a single word. And I think that word is **bargainer**.

A bargain can be thought of as an agreement, but unlike `agreement` and its other synonyms, `bargain` implies that it's *[favorable to the buyer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bargain#bargain__2)*.

> 2. A thing bought or offered for sale much more cheaply than is usual or expected (Oxford)

You *buy* a car *'at a bargain'* if you buy it cheap. The salesman doesn't *'sell it at a bargain'* if he sells it for a higher profit.

Since most dictioaries list `bargainer` as a derivative of bargain without its dedicated meaning, the closest I could get for a reference was [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=professional%20bargainer)

> **professional bargainer**
>
> In retail, a **customer** who feels they are absolved, for whatever reason, from paying the full retail, or even sale price, of an item.

This was just to demonstrate that a bargainer is usually understood to be a (prospective) customer.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, the term ***savvy shopper*** is often used.

> **Savvy:**
>
> 1. Well informed and perceptive; shrewd.
> 2. Knowledgeable or proficient.

thefreedictionary.com

Comment: Similarly a "canny customer".